# CodeIgniter not returning same results as query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm running a query selecting data from 2 different tables:

```
$this->db->select('a.any_id, a.name');
$this->db->from('table1 a, table2 b');
$this->db->where('a.any_id = b.any_id');
$this->db->where('b.other_id = "$myId"');
```

If a run this query in PHPmyAdmin it returns some results, but when I run this code in CodeIgniter it returns an empty array.

Any tip? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: ```$this->db->select('a.any_id, a.name');
    $this->db->from('table1 a, table2 b');
    $this->db->where('a.any_id = b.any_id', NULL);
    $this->db->where('b.other_id = "$myId"', NULL);$query = $this->db->get();return $query->result();```

Comment: No, it didn't work. Same 0 results as before

Comment: and This ```$this->db->select('a.any_id, a.name');
    $this->db->from('table1 a, table2 b');
    $this->db->where('a.any_id', 'b.any_id');
    $this->db->where('b.other_id', $myId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();```

Comment: You might need to look at using db->join()  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#join

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are trying to join two tables and your not using codeigniter `$this->db->join()` scroll down on the userguide to you see the join() https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

```
public function example($myID) {
   $this->db->select('a.any_id, a.name');
   $this->db->from('table1 a', 'LEFT');
  // $this->db->from('table1 a');
   $this->db->join('table2 b', 'b.any_id = a.any_id', 'LEFT');
   $this->db->where('a.any_id', 'b.any_id');
   $this->db->where('b.other_id', $myId);
   $query = $this->db->get();

   return $query->result();
}
```

Then vardump it.

Comment: Putting multiple tables in the FROM is fine, its called a CROSS JOIN, then if you add constraints to the WHERE clauses `tablea=tableb`, it effectively converts it into an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all and thanks for the responses.

It had nothing to do with using the join clause.

I just changed

```
$this->db->where('b.other_id = "$myId"');
```

to

```
$this->db->where('b.other_id', $myId);
```

and worked perfectly. Not sure yet why, as the first line works perfect for simple queries.

Comment: The first is just using the initial line as the full where, the 2nd is splitting it saying 'this column' = this constraint. both are valid though the first should be written like: `$this->db->where('b.other_id = '. $myId);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        $this->db->select('a.any_id.*,table2.name');
        $this->db->from('table1 a'); 
        $this->db->join('tabl2 b', 'a.id=b.id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('a.id',$id);      
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```